How do I list objects from public AWS S3 buckets using aws-sdk-php (v3.305.1) using anonymous clients?
So I have a public bucket which can directly be access by a link (can see the data if I copy paste that link on the browser).
However, when I try access the bucket via aws-sdk-php (v3.305.1) library it gives me the error:
"The authorization header is malformed; a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential."
This is the code I have written to access the objects of my public bucket:
$s3Client = new S3Client([
   "version" => "latest"
   "region" => "us-east-1"
   "credentials" => false // since its a public bucket
]);

$data = $s3Client->listObjectsV2([
   "bucket" => "my bucket name"
]);

As per the AWS Documentation it says this it using the code above so I am not really sure why I am getting the error.
So how do I go about fixing this error ?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_configuration.html here's where that false setting is documented.  Seems like you're doing it right to me

Yeah looks like it so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

"can see the data if I copy paste that link on the browser"  The ability to see objects in the bucket with a browser does not necessarily mean the bucket is public and allows ListObjects and related permissions.

Assuming that link is to s3.amazonaws.com or whatever s3 url, then yeah, it implies the unsigned requests coming from the browser have permission to access the files.

Also when I use the cli to list objects from the bucket with the --no-sign-request option I am able to list all the objects from the bucket.

Fair enough, then it sounds like a SDK bug to me.
